# Android breaking when closed

Tags: android

I have an app which displays content on the screen with opengl and gets touch events in the activity file. When I close the app (home button/hold home button then select it) the graphics no longer display and doesn't handle touch events.

The touch event error:

```
I/InputDispatcher﹕ Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (173, 122).
```

173, 122 are just where I clicked.

OnStop/OnRestart/OnPause/OnResume:

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    try {
        appThread.join();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    view.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    view.onPause();
}
```

`view` is: `view = new GLSurfaceView(this);`

EDIT: Another problem is that when I lock my phone while it's running, I am unable to get into my phone and need to restart.

What causes these problems and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is unclear when the problem happens and what component it affects: does your app ignore events, or does the system stop reacting after you close your app? Just in case, a view can have the attribute `android:clickable`.

Comment: It works perfectly (touch included) until I close it

Comment: `appThread.join();` -- hmmm... try to comment it out. What happens then?